# Duplicate results on JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, phpmyadmin

Here is my question : I am trying to get all the games of a class. the class can host a game, or have a game in another class.

games table have : guest_class (ID of class) and host_class(ID of class)

classes table have : id_class (ID of class)

An example I am trying to get the games of the class 1.
There are only 2 games with class 1.

```
id_game: 1, id_class: 1, host_class: 3, guest_class: 1,
id_game: 2, id_class: 1, host_class: 1, guest_class: 6,
```

Why am I getting duplicated results ?

QUERY

```
var classID = Number(req.query.searchValue);
var query = `SELECT * FROM games g 
LEFT JOIN classes c ON c.id_class = g.host_class OR c.id_class = g.guest_class 
WHERE ( g.host_class = ? OR g.guest_class = ? )`;
con2.query(query, [classID,classID] , function (err, result) {
```

RESULT

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id_game: 1,
    date: 2017-12-04T23:00:00.000Z,
    host_class: 3,
    guest_class: 1,
    host_score: 34,
    guest_score: 74,
    tournament_id: 0,
    group_id: 1,
    statistics: '',
    incidents: '',
    id_class: 1},
  RowDataPacket {
    id_game: 1,
    date: 2017-12-04T23:00:00.000Z,
    host_class: 3,
    guest_class: 1,
    host_score: 34,
    guest_score: 74,
    tournament_id: 0,
    group_id: 1,
    statistics: '',
    incidents: '',
    id_class: 3},
  RowDataPacket {
    id_game: 2,
    date: 2017-11-30T23:00:00.000Z,
    host_class: 1,
    guest_class: 6,
    host_score: 84,
    guest_score: 57,
    tournament_id: 0,
    group_id: 1,
    statistics: '',
    incidents: '',
    id_class: 1},
  RowDataPacket {
    id_game: 2,
    date: 2017-11-30T23:00:00.000Z,
    host_class: 1,
    guest_class: 6,
    host_score: 84,
    guest_score: 57,
    tournament_id: 0,
    group_id: 1,
    statistics: '',
    incidents: '',
    id_class: 6} ]
```

Comment: why use left join? there are game.class without match on classes?

Comment: And why join to classes if only have `class_id`?? and you already have that in games.

Comment: I have the ID of the classes in game, but not the names and other information of classes, for clarity I did not put those info in RESULT

Comment: I would like to get info from the two classes, but only when the games have the ID I seek for host or for guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try like this;

```
select * from games where id_game IN (
SELECT g.id_game FROM games g 
LEFT JOIN classes c ON c.id_class = g.host_class OR c.id_class = g.guest_class 
WHERE ( g.host_class = ? OR g.guest_class = ? )
group by g.id_game)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the games of the class 1. There are only 2 games with class 1.

You dont need a join for that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM games g 
WHERE g.host_class = ? OR g.guest_class = ?
```